# Difference between "<?php" and "<?"?

Tags: php

When I started learning about php I learned that when I want to call php I needed to put the php code between the this code `<?php ?>` but I also seen that `<? ?>` so I've stucked to working with the second option.

Is there any difference between the two of them because recently I've seen that on one machine the second option didn't worked while the first did so it confused me very well.

Comment: Duplicate: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/938236)

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos I know it's a dup. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156102; http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142238; http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135364

Comment: Note: the duplicate is a bit outdated, it doesn't note that [Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: Sorry did not know they are referenced as short tags so did not know how to search for it on google.Thank you for your prompt helpfull answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?` is called short tag that it is discouraged because it needs a specific php.ini setting to be enabled. I've ran into a few shared servers where `<?` is disabled. Therefore you should try to use `<?php` instead.

You can also [check the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference other than a configuration setting that is needed for

See details here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php